# A community of persistent pseudonomous email redirections

Tags: email, anonymization

I have an unusual need, and I'm hoping there's a no-/low-code way to answer it.

I want about 10 people to be able to email each other in such a way that they can use their own email address/accounts/clients to send to pre-selected anonymous email addresses. The recipients will see only the sender's own pre-selected anonymous email address, and be able to reply in kind.

For example:

1. User 1 sends from `user1@external.com` to
   `anonymous-user-2@internal.com`
2. User 2 receives at `user2@external.com`
   an email from `anonymous-user-1@internal.com` to
   `anonymous-user-2@internal.com`
3. User 2 replies from `user2@external.com`
   to `anonymous-user-1@internal.com`
4. User 1 receives at
   `user1@external.com` an email from `anonymous-user-2@internal.com` to
   `anonymous-user-1@internal.com`

Ideally I could also rewrite part or
all of the subject line according to set rules.

Does any of this make sense/is it achievable? The level of security required need not be vast (IP/header deletion isn't a critical feature) nor am I worried about logs being kept. This is really in aid of a sort of game.

[EDIT] I'm hoping for an online service that can handle this, and am happy to pay up to £10ish/month (call it US$15)

Comment: Welcome to you community.  It makes sense to me.  You question may benefit from adding details such as desired price (or gratis) and operating system(s).

Comment: Hi there @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket, thanks!
I'm hoping for an online service that can handle this, and am happy to pay up to £10ish/month (call it US$15)

Comment: You're welcome.  Adding that information to you question (vs. as a comment) will be your best bet.  Comments sometimes get deleted and can't easily be edited after 5 minutes.

Comment: anon.penet.fi used to do this, but it closed down years ago,

Answer (score 0):

A quick [Google search for 'anonymous remailer service'](https://www.google.com/search?q=anonymous+remailer+service) turned up one run by Harvard Law School (the [Berkman Mostly Anonymous Remailing Service](https://cyber.harvard.edu/anon_remail/)). This appears to meet your stated needs, but you may want to inquire if this is open to everyone, or if you must be affiliated with the school in some way - the page linked does not say either way.